# В каких случаях переменная в Python воспринимается как булева?

Tags: python

Простая задача: получить что-то на вход (число, слово, не важно что), а затем вывести это.

Если пользователь ничего не ввел - сообщить ему об этом.

Задачу решить с помощью оператора логического сравнения " != ".

Написал скрипт, который работает одинаково в обоих случаях (выводит то, что я ввел или пустоту, если ничего не ввел):

```
word = input("Напиши хоть что-то: ")
if  word != 0:
    print("Ты ввел вот это:", word)
else:  
    print("Ты ничего не ввел. Молодец...")
```

Вряд ли оператор сравнения в данном случае срабатывает как оператор присваивания, так что пришёл к выводу, что в данном случае переменная не воспринимается компилятором как булева, хотя, как мне известно, любое ненулевое значение переменной приравнивается к True, а нулевое - к False. То есть условие сравнивает переменную с нулем как с числом, и, естественно, если ничего не ввести, то "ничего" != 0. Но, в результате опытов, пришел к следующему скрипту, который работает.

```
word = input("Напиши хоть что-то: ")
if  (not word) != 0:
    print("Ты ввел вот это:", word)
else:  
    print("Ты ничего не ввел. Молодец...")
```

Итак, вопрос: в каких случаях компилятор интерпретирует переменную как булево значение и сравнивает с логическим нулем, а в каких как переменную и сравнивает её значение с нулем как с числом? Заранее спасибо за ответ)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: если кратко: Если нет операнда сравнения - преобразовывает в `bool`, если есть сравнение - оставляет исходный тип и проводит сравнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что не "**переменная** воспринимается как булева", а "**выражение**, которое проверяет `if` воспринимается как булево.

Ваш пример:

```
if  word != 0:
```

Тут строка сравнивается с числом. Это выражение всегда будет истинным, потому что никакая строка не может быть равна числу - это разные типы.
А вот если вы напишете так:

```
if word:
```

То для того, чтобы решить, выполнился `if` или нет, то, что стоит между `if` и `:` приводится к типу `bool`. Если там какое-то сложное выражение, оно разбирается дальше, но суть в том, что преобразование в `bool` идёт тогда, когда требуется `bool` значение. Например, если будет что-то такое:

```
if word and phrase:
```

То, поскольку оператор `and` логический, тут уже к `bool` для проверки начнут приводиться отдельные части этого выражения и всё будет несколько сложнее, потому что там тоже своя хитрая логика у логических операций с не булевскими переменными.

Но в общем, если резюмировать кратко:
`if <выражение>:` - это тоже самое, что `if bool(<выражение>):` и именно из-за этого тут происходит приведение к типу `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что и с чем вы сравниваете. В вашем случае, если вы хотите сравнивать строку с 0, то это не совсем правильно. Тогда сравнивайте длину строки:

```
word = input('Напиши хоть что-то: ')
if len(word) != 0:
    print(f'Ты ввел вот это: {word}')
else:
    print(f'Ты ничего не ввел')
```

Для примера:

```
print(False == 0)
```

Вывод:
True

Comment: А разве пустой ввод не приравнивается к False? Тогда, по идее, False != False получается False. Просто в коде по типу ( if word: ... ) нулевой ввод приравнивается к False и всё работает. Прости за банальные вопросы, если что)

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, пусть меня поправят, но пустой ввод, это пустой ввод, а не False. Даже ему соответствует код ASCII. То есть, в этой строке есть как минимум код Enter.

Comment: @Johan длина пустого ввода равна 0, непохоже, что там есть какой-то код

Comment: "она" в данном случае это что? Проверьте 0 == False. Что там чему равно

Comment: Да я не спорю )) Сам уже запутался.